# MySQL LEFT RIGHT JOIN syntax fluency

Tags: mysql

I'm coming across this situation alot, I'll have a query that will have one table needed in a join condition that may have no entries therefore requiring me to use a LEFT JOIN. I can't wrap my head around the syntax when it's used with more than 1 join.

I'll have:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
FROM A, B, C
WHERE A.id = C.id
AND C.aid = A.id
AND B.cid = C.id
```

Along comes D with the possibility of being empty and I have to rewrite the query and run into problems.

How can I simply join D to any one of these tables?

Comment: I see someone found there way to my jquery not working question hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to never specify more than one column on FROM clause.

For clarity, it's better to always:

- Use JOIN clause
- Use aliases
- Specify columns of joined tables on left side of equal sign

Example:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM ATable a
INNER JOIN BTable b
  ON b.id = a.id
INNER JOIN CTable c
  ON c.id = a.id
WHERE a.someColumn = 'something'
```

Not sure about MySQL, but in some other SQL flavors, you can use the same on UPDATES and DELETES, like:

```
DELETE FROM a
FROM ATable a
INNER JOIN BTable b
  ON b.id = a.id
INNER JOIN CTable c
  ON c.id = a.id
WHERE a.someColumn = 'something'
```

or

```
UPDATE a
SET  something = newValue
FROM ATable a
INNER JOIN BTable b
  ON b.id = a.id
INNER JOIN CTable c
  ON c.id = a.id
WHERE a.someColumn = 'something'
```

Answer (score 5):

You're much better off explicitly specifying all of your JOINs. That should make things much clearer.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*
    FROM A
        INNER JOIN C
            ON C.aid = A.id
        INNER JOIN B
            ON B.cid = C.id
        LEFT JOIN D
            ON C.did = d.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax below should help you.  The basic premise is whatever table is listed LEFT is the required.. the table (or alias) on the right is optional.  I understand you don't quite get it, and your syntax sample shows that (not meant to criticize) as you are joining from A -> C and C back to A on a different field.  If this is the case where two fields are in the "C" table that BOTH point to A, you would re-join to A as a second alias...

```
select 
      Want.*,
      Maybe.*,
      SecondA.*,
      B.*
   From
      A as Want
         LEFT JOIN C as Maybe
            on Want.ID = Maybe.ID

            JOIN A as SecondA
               on Maybe.AID = SecondA.ID
            JOIN B
               on Maybe.ID = B.cID
```

So, this query is stating I want everything from Table A (alias Want -- left side/first table in the list)  Regardless of there being a match in Table C (alias Maybe) where the ID keys match.

Notice the next joins going down from "C" back to the second instance of "A" and table B.  I have those as just joins... So the relationship between the "Maybe" alias, and that of second instance of "A" and "B" are JOIN (required).

Hopefully this gives some better clarification on HOW it works.

Now, for your real-life query.  If you can describe what you are looking for, and your sample table structures / result expections, listing that could offer more explicit solution to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help

```
SELECT 
A.*, B.*, C.*
FROM A
inner join C on(A.id = C.id)
inner join B on(B.cid = C.id)
```